# Implementing asynchronous http requests on Android with AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, httpwebrequest, android-asynctask

I'm building this client for a web service. 
Pretty much everything makes requests to a server and now what I do is, I open a new thread and put all my requests in the same thread. That means I'm making all my requests in a serial way inside the thread and that turns into a lot of waiting for the user. Aiming to make the application faster, I want to make every server request in an asynchronous way.

I have a Networking class that handles all the HTTP requests I need and I'm thinking of making it so that every request starts its own thread.

I'm thinking of using ASyncTask for this but I noticed that with ASyncTask I'd need a class for each of my http requests (a class for GET, POST, PUT, etc). Is that the best way of doing it? is there a more efficient/clean way of doing this? What do you guys suggest.

Comment: Why do you think that y using `AsyncTask` you would have to create one class for each http request? `AsyncTask` just offloads some work to a separate thread and does not enforce any implementation patterns.. Just call Networking class from `doInBackground`.

Comment: denis.solonenko: hmmm. That's an idea to consider. I'm gonna try and see how that could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a design decision that will depend on exactly what you are up to. There are various ways in Android to execute tasks depending on whether the user is waiting for some data or is being notified later on once the background task completes.

I would suggest you to look at [this](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html) post that compares various task mechanisms in Android. Apart from this also go through the java.util.concurrent package.

I'm sorry this is not a concrete answer, but take it from me - it mostly depends on how are you trying to serve the user. So one can only suggest ideas. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is a design decision and I really looking for an insight on what to go for. That article is really interesting and I'm onto reading it!